# Fastest way to upload multiple images in php

Tags: php, file-upload

Is there any fastest way to upload multiple images to server in php.

I have made a page where i have to upload 10 images.

And i have 10 input file fields.

Upload of image is normal still i want is there any way for it.

Comment: For HTML input file tag, you can set it to select multiple files. However, the upload speed of using 1 input tag and 10 input tags have no significant difference.

Comment: i have 10 input fields

Comment: As I said, it has no difference in terms of speed at all.

Answer (score -1):

many ways for upload file:

1. You can change inpuit file to multiple for select multiple file at once
2. using HTML5 for upload. See:

> https://gist.github.com/mbaljeetsingh/250ad2203641e9067f13

Comment: i have 10 input fields